# Lightning taking too long to show record inserted

Tags: apex, lightning

I have Insert ProductSchedule in under Opportunity Product on Click of a Button which calls my class. It is working fine in Salesforce Classic but in lightning,
it is taking too much time and showing record after refreshing 3 to 4 times.

I have use
return new pagereference('/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+OpportunityLineItem+'/view');

Comment: can u please upload your class.so that i can take reference from there.

Comment: Sorry, I can't but i am inserting ProductSchedule and then redirecting.